# Android capture event when app is closing forcibly

Tags: android

I want to store user logged out time in the database(for maintaining the user analytics) when the android app forcibly closed by user. Is it possible to capture event in MainActivity?

can any one suggest the better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Please check this post. It explain briefly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093957/logout-user-when-app-gets-killed

Answer (score 0):

there is no reliable way for this event detection - this would be kind-of insecure to inform app that it's going to be killed allowing to execute some code at that moment (as in your case - database handling). user clearly wants to stop this app, when it would get a possibility to execute some code just before gets killed then it may e.g. leave some alarm for now + 10secs in `AlarmManager` to restart some background service. this is opposite to what user wanted

best you can do is listening when last `Activity` is destroyed (`onDestroy` call), but this may occur in multiple cases, no ony force stop app by user. use some `static int` and `++` when `Activity` is created and `--` when destroyed or use `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` on never APIs