# How to clear a task in Android and change the root activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, task

**Situation**

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C

When Activity C starts I'd like C becomes the root Activity, while A and B finish.

How can I achieve this?

**UDPATE**

I am on Level 10, so I can't use CLEAR_TASK flag that is for level 11 and superior.**strong text**

Comment: You want A and B only to finish med C is launched? Otherwise you could call finish() before you start a new activity.

Comment: Take a look at this similar [post][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979171/clear-all-activities-in-a-task

Comment: @Carnal: yes I know but I have to call finish on both A and B only just starts C

Comment: @DamienPraca sorry but CLEAR_TASK is only for Level >= 11 I am on Level 10

Comment: Well, I don't know if this is a good idea. But you could create a List of Activities, and in A and B you add yourself to this list, and in C, you take out this two activities and call finish() on them. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE FOR SOLUTION

I solve it using startActivityForResult and dispatching back a result.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following line the entry of activity C in the manifest

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear

Answer (score 0):

put a flag into your launching intent:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

example: Intent launchC = new Intent(getApplicacionContext(),nameC.class);

launchC.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

basiclly same that previous answer, but previous method obligates clear task every time that you launch C, but with the flag you can have a different control.
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

after calling

```
startactivity() method call this.finish();
```

on A, then B

hope this fulfill your requirement

Comment: I have to finish A and B only when C starts, I don't want to call finish() when I start B from A.

Comment: did u mean u have to end A and B , which are in pause state Simultaneously  when C is Running?