# How to avoid multiple instances of same Activity without using singleInstance or singleTask launchMode?

Tags: android, android-activity

This is the behavior I'm looking for:

Start the App and navigating => Activity A > B > C
Then I press Home button and open the App again => Go back to C (with stack A B C)

Now I have a service running who creates notifications.
Click on the notification => Clear whatever is in the stack and open A then X from onNewIntent() (stack is now A > X)

But the current behavior when I click on a notification is A B C A X (X on top)

As I understand, this is happening because of the wrong context. See the following post for more information about the blank context issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/24999724

So my conclusion is to use the "standard" launchMode and find a way to clear the stack from all activites when clicking on notifications. Is there any patterns to implement in order to get this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with "wrong context". If you want clicking on a `Notification` to clear the task stack and start a new instance of `ActivityA`, then use the following flags in the `Intent` you put in the `Notification`:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVIY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Assuming that `ActivityA` is still active (not finished) and at the root of the task stack, his will clear the task stack back to `ActivityA` (including clearing the existing instance of `ActivityA`), then create a new instance of `ActivityA` and call `onCreate()`, etc.

If you want to reuse the existing instance of `ActivityA`, you can use this instead:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVIY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

Assuming that `ActivityA` is still active (not finished) and at the root of the task stack, his will clear the task stack back to `ActivityA` (**without** clearing the existing instance of `ActivityA`), then call `onNewIntent()` on the existing instance of `ActivityA`.