# onNewIntent() not being called when there is another activity on top

Tags: android

Seems that `onNewIntent()` of my MainActivity is not being called when I have another `Activity` on top of it, if I close the second `Activity` it does get called just fine, it's like the other `Activity` which is on top is blocking the messages? Both `Activity`s are set to singleTop in the manifest and I set the `Intent` from a notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If another `Activity` is visible over an existing `Activity` the the first will be paused and then stopped. Consequently no code in the first `Activity` will be executed. This is standard for Android and the `Activity` life-cycle.

Comment: So if I wanted to call a function when the notification is clicked and there are other activities on top, how would I do that without creating a new activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably already searched google - there are lots of questions on why onNewIntent is not called.

It might depend on which android version you are doing tests, but you might try adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag to your intent - even though you have it in your manifest, together with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

> intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

this will remove activities above you activity which you want to launch.

But if your intent is to keep two activities alive, and switch between them, then look into [android:taskAffinity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: I tried adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP but it did not close the activity which is on top, it doesn't do anything. Would be fine for me to close any activities which are on top of the main one. Any ideas why it did not work?

Comment: Actually it worked fine, not sure why it didn't first time, thanks!

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to work all the time, weird - if I press the home button and then I click on the notification, it won't clear the activity on top of it anymore, it just brings it to view.

Comment: see this so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873131/android-clear-task-flag-not-working-for-pendingintent

Comment: I think it's fine now, I had some code on my onCreate() to fix some other bug caused by the android installer launching my application in different way, changed it to this and seems fine now:
`/* if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) { */

if (!isTaskRoot()) {
 finish();
 return;
}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the correct launch mode is set for the Activity receiving the Intent. Set `launchMode` to "`singleTop`" in their package, or if a client used the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag when calling `startActivity(Intent)`.

Comment: It is set to singleTop but looks like as Squonk pointed out, when there is another activity on top of it, the activity beneath won't execute any code.