# Is there a method to clear all the task in an app (Android)?

Tags: android, android-activity, task

Quick question, just want to know if i have 2 tasks in my project. Is there any way to clear both of them in a single go. This is because when i try to clear both task to quit my app, only one is clearing and the another one is still alive which prevents me from quitting the application.

```
finishAffinity();
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Any suggestions to solve this  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to close all the task in an android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765674/is-there-a-way-to-close-all-the-task-in-an-android-project)

Comment: Why 2 questions for same thing? @rana

Comment: You already asked this question. You need to explain why you have multiple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You could use:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

or else Use `android:noHistory="true"` on the splash activity in the manifest file.

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979171/clear-all-activities-in-a-task

Comment: This doesn't work if the app is split into 2 tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to quit both tasks, then you need to do it like this:

When you want to quit, you send a broadcast `Intent` with the ACTION set to something like `"my.package.name.QUIT"`.

In all of your activities, declare and register a listener, like this:

```
registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("my.package.name.QUIT"));
```

When `onReceive()` of your `BroadcastReceiver` is called, you should call `finish()`.

This will ensure that all of your activities finish, regardless of where they are running.

**NOTE: I still don't understand why you have multiple tasks and I think that you need to address that problem. The solution here is really just a hack because you probably don't want multiple tasks.**